# C Concurrent Processes and a Pipe

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I have the following code:

```
for(i=0; i < argc; i++)
{
     pipe(fd[2]);
     pid=fork();

     if (pid > 0)
     {
          close(fd[1]);
          // read the string, and print it
     }
     else if (pid == 0)
     {
          close(fd[0]);
          // write the file name to the main process
          break;
     }    
}

// wait for all processes to finish
```

So basically, it outputs each file name in sequential order:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

But if I put `printf("%d\n", getpid())` after the for loop, the outputs seems concurrent. Some processes with a higher process id are printed first.

My question is, the way I do the pipe read/write inside the for loop, is it sequential or concurrent?

Comment: The most significant part of the code, i.e. the read / write on the pipe, is missing.  Post the full code, or at least enough for others to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Seems it will be sequential due to the fact that the parent process reads from the pipe and that read blocks until the child writes to it. Which also means the parent will not do the next `fork` until each child that was just forked has done its write. This assumes each `read` consumes everything that was written - which is not actually guaranteed to be the case.

Comment: the 'child' path should end with a call to `exit()` not just jump out of the loop.

Comment: so as to not run out of available file descriptors, after the parent completes it's read, it should close the read end of the pipe[].  after the child completes it's write, it should close the write end of the pipe.   The parent should call `wait()` or `waitpid()` before jumping back to the top of the loop.  The result will be that both ends of the pipe will be closed in both processes when done, However, it would be much better, since it is different processes, to use `named pipes` rather than the current method.

Comment: @kaylum how can I make it concurrent? I need each child process to process a file, but not sequentially. Its the requirement for my assignment.

Comment: @M.Averbach How about: 1) start a bunch of children 2) wait for all of them to finish. Instead of what you have now, which seems to be: 1) start a child 2) wait for it to finish 3) start another child 4) wait for it to finish 5) ...

Comment: @immibis I thought about that, but the problem is that after all the children break out of the loop, they are running concurrently, but I can't communicate with the parent process anymore. I need each child process to send the filename to the parent, and for this to be concurrent. The part after the for loop is read only once by the parent process, the rest of the times its the children.

Comment: @M.Averbach Did you know you can create more than one pipe?

Comment: @immibis I create a pipe right before each fork call.

Comment: @M.Averbach So what stops you from creating a bunch of pipes, starting children so that one child writes to each pipe, and then (once all the children are started) reading from each pipe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103148/discussion-between-m-averbach-and-immibis).

Answer (score 1):

printing after the `for()` loop the value returned from `getpid()` will be printed both for the (many) child pids and the parent pid.

There is no guarantee as to what process will execute to the call to `printf()` first.

so the pid values can (and as you have seen) probably will) be printed in some 'random' order.

Answer (score 1):

When you fork a child process, the parent and child both run concurrently. Unless they do something that synchronizes them, the order that they each run is unpredictable.

In the case of your `for` loop, the reads and writes in the pipes are synchronizing the processes: the parent can't return from `read()` until after the child has called `write()`. And they won't fork new children until both have done this.

But after the loop is done, there's nothing synchronizing the processes, so they'll all print their PIDs in any order.